# Update value in Firebase database through Android Recyceler View

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am working on a app which show Notices fetched from firebase database. I have a field on the database as date, title, text! The text will be unique, So I am taking is at primary key to fetch value from database.

I have a Recycler view for update the values but when I am trying to update the value, sometime it works fine but sometime is modifying all values of the database. Is there any wrong, I am doing in the recycler view. here is my code..

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NoticeAdminHolder holder, int position) {

    Notices n = list.get(position);
    holder.date.setText(n.getDate());
    holder.title.setText(n.getTitle());
    holder.text.setText(n.getText());

    text = holder.text.getText().toString();

    holder.update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Notices f = new Notices();

            f.setDate(holder.date.getText().toString());
            f.setTitle(holder.title.getText().toString());
            f.setText(holder.text.getText().toString());


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            final View view = v;
            builder.setTitle("Confirm");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to Update Record?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   updateValue(text,f, view);
                   // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), holder.title.getText()+" "+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Do nothing
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class NoticeAdminHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    EditText date, title, text;
    Button update, delete;
    public NoticeAdminHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoticeDate);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoticeTitle);
        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNoticeDetails);
        update = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    }
}


public void updateValue(String text, Notices f, final View v){
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mDatabase.getReference();
    final View view = v;
    final Notices notice = f;
    myRef.child("notices")
            .orderByChild("text")
            .equalTo(text)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        key = childSnapshot.getKey();
                        myRef.child("notices").child(key).setValue(notice).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                                builder.setCancelable(true);
                                builder.setTitle("Success");
                                builder.setMessage("Data is Updated Successfully ! Please refresh the activity to reflect the changes.");
                                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                       // v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),NoticeAdminRecycler.class));
                                        ((Activity)v.getContext()).finish();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Error Occured !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Database Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

          }
```

Comment: What do you mean by modifying all values of the database? What does the value change to?

Comment: means that I have a node notice in firebase, under that child nodes are created with fields date, title, text. When I run the app, and update the value of particular child of node notice, it works fine. But sometime it behaves irregularly and modify more than a child of a node notices.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text value inside the clickListener.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NoticeAdminHolder holder, int position) {

Notices n = list.get(position);
holder.date.setText(n.getDate());
holder.title.setText(n.getTitle());
holder.text.setText(n.getText());

//Do not set 'text' here, as it is the text of last binder holder, and not necessarily the one you clicked on

holder.update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Notices f = new Notices();

        f.setDate(holder.date.getText().toString());
        f.setTitle(holder.title.getText().toString());
        f.setText(holder.text.getText().toString());

        //Setting the 'text' here ensures that the node you want to change is the node you clicked on.
        text = holder.text.getText().toString();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        final View view = v;
        builder.setTitle("Confirm");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to Update Record?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               updateValue(text,f, view);
               // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), holder.title.getText()+" "+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks! that is the problem.. But I can not place the text value inside the click listener, because I am considering it as a key value to update the database, but if someone changed the value of the text itself, I will not able to update the value in the database. I think I need to add another field in the database for key value, which can not be edited by the user!

Comment: Or you can have hidden textview that holds the original text. That way you can access the the original text too. You'll have to update the hidden text value after changes to the database have been made.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped solve your  question.

Comment: Do you have also other properties that have the same value for the `text` property? Please responde with @.